# Insert filename into text file with sed

Tags: sed, filenames

I've been learning about sed and finding it very useful, but cannot find an answer to this in any of the many guides and examples ... I'd like to insert the filename of a text file, minus its path and extension, into a specific line within the text itself. Possible?

Comment: I recommend to provide more information on the environment. I predict solution proposals via shell variable replacement. So please state the kind of shell you are using. Also other information might help, maybe consult (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, sorry.  Linux Ubuntu 16.04.2 and GNU sed 4.2.2

Answer (score 1):

In such cases, the correct starting point should be man pages. Manual of sed does not provide a feature for sed to understand "filename", but sed does support inserting a text before/after a line.

As a result you need to isolate the filename separatelly , store the text to a variable and inject this text after/before the line you wish.

Example:

```
$ a="/home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/cpu.sh"
$ a="${a##*/}";echo "$a"
cpu.sh
$ a="${a%.*}"; echo "$a"
cpu

$ cat file1
LOCATION 0 X 0
VALUE 1a 2 3
VALUE 1b 2 3
VALUE 1c 2 3

$ sed "2a $a" file1   # Inject the contents of variable $a after line2
LOCATION 0 X 0
VALUE 1a 2 3
cpu
VALUE 1b 2 3
VALUE 1c 2 3

$ sed "2i $a" file1   # Inject the contetns of variable $a before line2
LOCATION 0 X 0
cpu
VALUE 1a 2 3
VALUE 1b 2 3
VALUE 1c 2 3

$ sed "2a George" file1  #Inject a fixed string "George" after line 2
LOCATION 0 X 0
VALUE 1a 2 3
George
VALUE 1b 2 3
VALUE 1c 2 3
```

Explanation:
`a="${a##*/}"`  : Removes all chars from the beginning of string up to last found slash /  (longer match)
`a="${a%.*}"`    : Remove all chars starting from the end of the string up to the first found dot . (short match) . You can also use %% for the longest found dot.
`sed "2a $a"`     : Insert after line 2 the contents of variable $a
`sed "2i $q"`     : Insert before line 2 the contents of $a

Optionally you can use `sed -i` to make changes in-place / in file under process

Answer (score 1):

wrt `I've been learning about sed` then you may have been wasting your time as there isn't a lot TO learn about sed beyond `s/old/new`. Sure there's a ton of other language constructs and things you could do with sed, but in practice you should avoid them all and simply use awk instead. If you edit your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output and add an awk tag then we can show you how to do whatever you want to do the right way.

Meanwhile, it sounds like all you need is:

```
$ cat /usr/tmp/file
a
b
c
d
e

$ awk 'NR==3{print gensub(/.*\//,"",1,FILENAME)} 1' /usr/tmp/file
a
b
file
c
d
e
```

The above inserts the current file name before line 3 of the open file. It uses GNU awk for gensub(), with other awks you'd just use sub() and a variable.

Comment: Good points, but you're missing the removal of the filename extension (suffix).

Comment: Any day now. :)